# Precompile C++ vendor Libraries (#include api.h)

Tags: c++, cmake, precompiled-headers

First of all, I have to say, that I am an absolute beginner in c++ and all the compiler stuff that is going on for native development.

What I am actually trying to do, is to create a NodeJS binding, to wrap an existing library. The library itself has a **api.h** which I can include in my wrapper an use it to built my Wrapper methods. The problem which I have, is that the library itself is quite large:

```
  src/  
    vendor/
      libA/..
      libB/..
      libC/..
      api.h 
      api.cpp 
    addon.cpp (where I am including the "vendor/api.h")
```

so every time I am compiling my addon.cpp all the libraries have to be recompiled again and again, which sucks. So what is the best way to compile the api once and use it in my addon.cpp (I am not using any of the libs in my addon only the api.h!)

By the way I am working on a **Ubuntu 14.04 and I am using Cmake** to perform the compilation:

To compile my addon with all the libraries, I am defining all the SOURCE_FILES like this:

```
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES
 "src/addon.cpp"
 "src/vendor/*.cpp" "src/vendor/*.h"
 "src/vendor/libA/*.c" "src/vendor/libA/*.h"
 "src/vendor/libB/*.cpp" "src/vendor/libB/*.h"
 "src/vendor/libC/*.c" "src/vendor/libC/*.h"
)

...
add_library(addon SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

To compile it, I am calling

```
cmake-js rebuild
```

cmake-js because it also loads some NodeJS required stuff, but the CMakeLists.txt file uses the normal cmake syntax

So any help would be really awesome, thanks!

Comment: You might have to explain what a NODE Wrapper is.

Comment: maybe you meant `file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES...`?

Comment: If you just modfiy `addon.cpp` this should **not** cause the other files to be recompiled

Comment: @JonathanPotter I mean a NodeJS Wrapper provides the api functions as JavaScript methods.. So you can use them as node binidings

Comment: @Nazar554 Yo, just fixed it

Comment: @m.s really? Ok, I am building it with npm install, which calls `cmake-js rebuild`

Comment: Yes, just thinking about it, none of your libraries in `src/vendor/` depend on any code written in `src/addon.cpp` (I just assume so) so there should be no need to recompile any of them when changing your addon code.

Comment: @AndyReimann Yes, there is no need to recompile, so maybe, there is a Cmake flag or so, I have to set?

Comment: First of all you could try to separate each library into an individual cmake project as well as a separate project for your addon which adds those directories of the libraries and defines proper dependencies to the projects. Don't know if that helps in the first place with your issue, but it cleans dependencies up at least so worth to try.

Comment: @AndyReimann yeah, you are right, I should separate the projects..

Comment: @kjo no problem, you can vote up the question here ;)

Answer (score -1):

Actually you are using your compiler the wrong way for nodejs. As your are in early stage of prototyping, you shouldn't use the method of ( thinking, trying, compile, observe, verify, feedback, modify, compile, ... )

When you are prototyping, you should create an empty DLL , that will at run time Load/Free the inner code for functionnaly. On windows the function are LoadLibrary/FreeLibrary.

Doing so, will allow you to use an iterative approach to fix your problem aka scripting abilities.

Once prototyping is done, create on top of that function the test function that will persist the validity domain and result expected and move the code into the DLLloader.

Avoid Cmake is the lazy way to compile , a simple command line is enought to compile your dll. Since you are going to prototype anyway, don't use cmake. Open a notedpad and use the commande line to generate your module.

So not only you will use a simple notepad or notepad++ , but you will have maximum speed and barely won't need a debugger at all.

So no need to recompile anymore, just-in-time prototying ability, real time fix and test.

Comment: I don't need to test the functionality of my module, I need to test the functions of the library in my module. But thx. Actually I can take this approach to prototype the node related methods ;)

Comment: It's the same, GetProcAdress ... thanks for the downvote anyway :(

Comment: Hmm, it wasn't me, but I would like to downvote, because I wrote, that I am on a Linux machine, and you are telling me somewhat about windows DLL bs... I also wrote, that I am using the cmd line for compiling, and you are telling something about how cool it is to use the command line for this simple stuff. Hey dude, you got the down vote, because of the trash factor of your answer and I totally agree with it.

Comment: You serious ??? DLL has nothing to do with windows, it's dynamic loading library .. they are both in linux or windows or qnx. Equivalence of GetProcAddress can be found in all dlopen familly and Cie..